# How do I add a pages breadcrumbs to an action in a Confluence Plugin?

Tags: plugins, velocity, confluence

I'm writing a plugin for Confluence and there isn't much documentation on what you can use in velocity vm files. I'm able to add a base breadcrumb that goes from Dashboard -> ActionName but I want to to do something similar to page edits where you get the full page breadcrumb followed by the action name.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
#applyDecorator("root")
    #decoratorParam("helper" $action.Helper)
    #decoratorParam("mode" "view")
    #decoratorParam("context" "page")
```

Any suggestions or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your action implement `PageAware`. I then passed the Page ID of the page I was coming from to the action, used `PageManager` to get the page based on ID and set the Page from the `PageAware` interface. The above code in the vm file will generate correct breadcrumbs.